# Low frequency video transmission

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radio-frequency

Can a video signal be transmitted for a short distance ($30\,\mathrm{cm}$) by a  very low frequency carrier ?

Here my concern is about frequencies $1\,\mathrm{hz} - 100 \,\mathrm{hz}$ .

Transmission distance can be  about $30\,\mathrm{cm}$.

Comment: No. The bandwidth of the transmitted signal has to be (up to the logarithm of the available excess signal to noise ratio) be the bandwidth of the signal that you want to transmit. Having said that, there are excellent electronics solutions for that kind of problem available these days.

Comment: @CuriousOne Don't conflate bandwidth with carrier frequency.  You can transmit information on a 0 Hz carrier.  It's called _baseband modulation_  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseband), but what you say about the band _width_ of the signal still is true.

Comment: @jameslarge: The OP gave us the bandwidth, not just the carrier frequency. As described it can't work.

Comment: @CuriousOne, My lyin' eyes skipped over the "...1 Hz to 100 Hz" sentence.  If that means that the OP wants the signal to contain no significant energy outside of that band, then of course you are right right.

Comment: @jameslarge: That's how I understood it. You are completely right, of course, that one could use baseband to transmit the video signal, but like Dirk pointed out in his answer below, 100Hz wouldn't make for a particularly fast frame rate or high enough resolution...

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is "yes" but the quality would be un-usable. As a very general rule of thumb, convert Hz into bits per second. Even with a really good compression ratio of (say) 20:1 you *might* be able to construct 1 frame of 40 x 40 pixels every second using 100Hz

Comment: If i transmit same video signal in 5Ghz and 5Ghz+50 Hz, will I be able to get a superimposed signal of 50 Hz frequency???

Comment: Yes, but the bandwidth is roughly bits per second of the maximum available frequency. In the above case it is still 50Hz, no matter what the carrier frequency.

Answer (score 0):

According to Shannon's capacity, see, [Shannon-Hartley formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem), a bandlimited noisy channel has a capacity $$\mathcal C = B\log_2\left(1+\frac{S}{N}\right),$$ where $B$ is the signal bandwidth, and $\frac{S}{N}$ is the signal to (normal) noise ratio.
In this question $B=100-1 = 99\text{Hz}$ and it is to carry a TV signal. A BW signal may need $100\text{kbit/sec} \le \mathcal C$, so then

$$\frac{S}{N} \approx 2^\tfrac {\mathcal C}{B}\approx 2^{100k/100}
=2^{1000}\approx 10^{300},$$
There is no such signal to noise ratio, not even in your imagination...